# How to group XML by parameters rows

Tags: xml, xslt

How to transform the xml:

```
<tags>

  <f28>
    <ROW f1='f28 row1 f1' f2='f28 row1 f2'/>
    <ROW f1='f28 row2 f1' f2='f28 row2 f2'/>
  </f28>

  <f16>
    <ROW f1='f16 row1 f1' f2='f16 row1 f2'/>
    <ROW f1='f16 row2 f1' f2='f16 row2 f2'/>
  </f16>

</tags>
```

in:

```
<doc name="number_id1">
 <parameter1>f28 row1 f1</parameter1>
 <parameter2>f28 row1 f2</parameter2>
 <parameter3>f16 row1 f1</parameter3>
 <parameter4>f16 row1 f2</parameter4>
</doc>

<doc name="number_id2">
 <parameter1>f28 row2 f1</parameter1>
 <parameter2>f28 row2 f2</parameter2>
 <parameter3>f16 row2 f1</parameter3>
 <parameter4>f16 row2 f2</parameter4>
</doc>
```

I need to transform the XML in another xml how I specified above using xslt.

---

### Edit:

Below example with real data. My xml:

```
<tags>
  <f28>
      <ROW f1='FULL' f5='no mutation' f6='p53'/>
      <ROW f1='STG' f5='certain' f6='BRCA1'/>
  </f28>
  <f16>
      <ROW f1='MAMA' f2='44' f3='Carcinoma'/>
      <ROW f1='Ovario' f2='46'f3='in situ'/>
  </f16>
</tags>
```

I want the following results :

```
<doc_name="number_id1">
 <parameter1>FULL</parameter1>
 <parameter2>no mutation</parameter2>
 <parameter3>p53</parameter3>
 <parameter4>MAMA</parameter4>
 <parameter5>44</parameter5>
 <parameter6>Carcinoma</parameter6>

</doc>

<doc_name="number_id2">
 <parameter1>STG</parameter1>
 <parameter2>certain</parameter2>
 <parameter3>BRCA1</parameter3>
 <parameter4>Ovario</parameter4>
 <parameter5>46</parameter5>
 <parameter6>in situ</parameter6>
</doc>
```

I'm using xsl 1.0 and I was unable to resolve this.

---

### Edit:

Correct Result is:

```
<doc doc_name="number_id1">
 <parameter1>FULL</parameter1>
 <parameter2>no mutation</parameter2>
 <parameter3>p53</parameter3>
 <parameter4>MAMA</parameter4>
 <parameter5>44</parameter5>
 <parameter6>Carcinoma</parameter6>

</doc>

<doc doc_name="number_id2">
 <parameter1>STG</parameter1>
 <parameter2>certain</parameter2>
 <parameter3>BRCA1</parameter3>
 <parameter4>Ovario</parameter4>
 <parameter5>46</parameter5>
 <parameter6>in situ</parameter6>
</doc>
```

Comment: Show your XSLT code. What version are you using? How are `f28` and `f16` related to `id1`, `id2`. Is this an example of something more complex? Please describe how the input is related to the output.

Comment: Perhaps you should rethink your target schema here, because (1) numbered elements will be difficult to process in a later stage, and (2) bundling 3 facts together in a single node is never a good idea. XML offers many ways to **structure** your data - take advantage of it.

Comment: I have rolled back your question to its original form and **added** your new version to it. Now please take another moment and explain the **logic** by which the data is grouped the way you show (is it merely the number of the original ROW within its parent element?) and  where do the doc ids come from. -- Note also that your requested output is not valid XML because (1) it has no root element and (2) `doc_name="number_id1"` is not a valid element name.

Comment: **Please DO NOT erase your original question after it has been answered!**

Comment: Ok ... I'm sorry. I only corrected the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are really proceeding with your strategy, try the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="tags/*">
            <doc name="number_id{count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1}">
                <xsl:for-each select="*/@*">
                    <xsl:element name="parameter{position()}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </doc>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT**

To group by `ROW`, try the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="ROW">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:element name="doc">
            <xsl:attribute name="doc_name">number_id<xsl:number/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:element name="parameter{position()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../following-sibling::*/ROW[position()=$pos]" mode="transfer"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tags/*[position() &gt; 1]/ROW"/>

    <xsl:template match="tags/*[position() &gt; 1]/ROW" mode="transfer">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:element name="parameter{position() + count(../../preceding-sibling::*/ROW[position()=$pos]/@*)}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it produces your desired output

```
<doc doc_name="number_id1">
    <parameter1>FULL</parameter1>
    <parameter2>no mutation</parameter2>
    <parameter3>p53</parameter3>
    <parameter4>MAMA</parameter4>
    <parameter5>44</parameter5>
    <parameter6>Carcinoma</parameter6>
</doc>
<doc doc_name="number_id2">
    <parameter1>STG</parameter1>
    <parameter2>certain</parameter2>
    <parameter3>BRCA1</parameter3>
    <parameter4>Ovario</parameter4>
    <parameter5>46</parameter5>
    <parameter6>in situ</parameter6>
</doc>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm gonna try execute the xslt!

Comment: This xslt make a group by tag <f28> or <f16> and not by <ROW>.

Comment: @JoelMLamsen. Thank. I tested and work very well. Do You know a good tutorial of XSLT ?